# Spancount in the grid layout manager i want one item in row 1 5 item in row 2 and rest 2 item per row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I want to implement grid layout manager of 1,5, and 2 item in row 1 I want one item in 2 I want 5 item then in rest I want 2 item. How to achieve this. Please help I am doing coding of the same but not able to achieve 5 in the 2nd row there is 3 only.

```
gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                return 5;
            else if (position == 1)
                return 1;
            else
                return 2;

        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention how many total spans you have across but I guess that it is 5.

The number of spans you define should be even divisible by the size of each item. So, divisible by 1 (of course), 5 and 2. 1*5*2=10, 10 spans will do. Create your `GridLayoutManager` with 10 spans.

Now, when you want just one item in a row, return 10 from `setSpanSizeLookup()`. If you want 2 items, then return 5. For 5 items return 2.

Your code will look something like this:

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return 10;
        else if (position < 6)
            return 2;
        else
            return 5;

    }
});
```

Comment: 5 item row is not dividing equally

Comment: but there is a lot of gap between 1'st row with one item and second row with 5 items?

Comment: @user3475052 There shouldn't be. Check your padding. Use the layout inspector to find out what's going on.